# SSL installation in Click-to-deploy Reposatory in GCP

Tags: wordpress, ssl, kubernetes

I am using the click-to-deploy repository for Wordpress installation.

the is a commend in the instruction [Update TLS certificate for WordPress](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/blob/master/k8s/wordpress/README.md#update-tls-certificate-for-wordpress)

> If you want to update the certificate that the application uses, copy
>   the new certificate and key pair in to the /tmp/tls.crt, and
>   /tmp/tls.key files, and execute the following command:

```
kubectl --namespace $NAMESPACE create secret tls $APP_INSTANCE_NAME-tls \
  --cert=/tmp/tls.crt --key=/tmp/tls.key --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

I saw so many video references and articles. they Use One VM and for that, they can start there shell very easily.

I am using Kubernaties it has three VM and if I run this command it will destroy the container infrastructure.

**Which cloud shell I run to write this commend so I can implement my SSL.**

I try it on Cluster this is the output:[image: Output of this commend in a cluster]

Answer (score 1):

From the output I can tell that Your environmental value `$NAMESPACE` is empty.

So the command:

```
kubectl --namespace $NAMESPACE create secret tls ...
```

is the same as

```
kubectl --namespace create secret tls ...
```

this is why Your output said `unknown command "secret" for "kubectl"` the flag `--namespace` used up word `create` as its value because `$NAMESPACE` was empty.

---

To fix this make sure the environmental values are set up correctly.

You can check their values by using:

```
echo $APP_INSTANCE_NAME
echo $NAMESPACE
```

If they are indeed empty or different than expected use like mentioned in the [guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/blob/master/k8s/wordpress/README.md#prepare-the-environment-1):

```
export APP_INSTANCE_NAME=wordpress-1
export NAMESPACE=default
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Probably you write the correct and precise answer.
right now I am not worried about the environment variable.
I am very new to Kubernetes. SO my question was
"Which cloud shell I run to write this commend so I can implement my SSL."
to be precious Its a one-click deployment and people like me need a simple solution to implement SSL we are not DevOps Engineer. We just start learning.

It will be very helpful if you say where I run this command. Some people say use kubectl some say do ssh.

I am confused. Just tell me where I run this commend?